# What is the range for nll_loss?

Tags: pytorch

I thought the range was only within the positive domain, but I am getting both negative numbers and positive numbers for F.nll_loss?

Why is that? I am confused. Softmax ranges from 0 to 1 and -log(0 to 1) is from infinity to 0. So, why am I getting negative numbers?

Comment: Can you specify how you call `F.nll_loss`. How was your input produced? `F.nll_loss` expects inputs that are already log likelihoods between -infinity and 0. The `nll_loss`basically performs: `loss(x, class) = -x[class]`

Comment: @McLawrence I simply call it as:  F.nll_loss(output, target) where output is a tensor and target is also a tensor

Comment: But how do you create output?

Comment: @McLawrence Sorry, it's the output of a CNN classifier (Inception) and target is a scalar representing an image label

Comment: Can you please add the entire code of the class of your CNN that produces the output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the function is implemented:

```
f = F.nll_loss

def NLLLoss(logs, targets):
    out = logs[range(len(targets)), targets]
    return -out.sum()/len(out)


i = torch.randn(3, 5)
print(i)


t = torch.empty(3).random_(0, 5).to(dtype=torch.long)
print(t)

o = f(i,t)
print(o)

f = NLLLoss

o = f(i,t)
print(o)

# tensor([[ 0.0684,  0.9493, -0.9932, -1.9325, -0.1642],
#         [ 1.7073,  0.8153, -0.6435, -1.0128,  0.9894],
#         [ 0.6948, -1.3770, -0.0932, -0.0951, -1.4226]])
# tensor([2, 0, 3])
# tensor(-0.2063)
# tensor(-0.2063)
```

It is just a sum of values and range can be from -inf to inf.

Comment: My target is a scalar. I'm not quite sure why it's using range(len(targets))? Can you explain what it does mathematically, as I am not understanding the code

Comment: Target are scalars, long values, and we process C=5 scalars from once. The distribution in here is normal, with mean=0 and std=1, so we do not reach the infinity but if we set some bad distribution we may.

Comment: If you have single target you may set `i = torch.randn(3, 1)`

Comment: I'm not too worried about reaching infinity, rather I'm confused why there are both positive and negative values. If the loss = -log(softmax(x)), then loss should be always positive, right?

Comment: nll_loss is -log(x) function, you don't put the `softmax` in there. This function can go from -inf to inf. -np.log(100) =-4.605170185988092,  -np.log(0.01) = 4.605170185988091

Comment: And if you use the `softmax` then indeed you are in positive range since softmax goes from [0,1), but you usually deal with `log_softmax` since if you do cross entropy.

Comment: Wait so nll_loss is simply -log(x)? What is x? Why does the source code sum up a bunch of stuff?

Comment: In here x is a scalar, representing the mean probability, that you would get if you would apply L=−(1/) ∑log(̂ ()), i=1,n.

Comment: Don't forget when we speak of likelihoods we need to have multiple samples N, else probability distribution for a single sample s1 would have mean=s1 and std=0.